# Evolution full text searching

Tags: email, search, evolution

the full text searching in Evolution (e.g, in the body of the mails) is very slow.

I see that, in each Mailbox setting, there is a checkbox to index the bodys of the message
(cf https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aga5.png)

But that does not work for me. At each time I restart evolution, the checkbox is unchecked.